# A User-Friendly Table - What Solution?

Tags: tables, html, css, jquery, bootstrap

Today, this is my table and if I select one of the row, it shows a select icon.

I want to make it more user-friend that you can see the whole row to be selected. Gmail has that functionality.

In my case, it is different because I have different color for every second row.

The question is how to make it more userfriendly in order to see a selected row instead of using icone symbol?

You also need to take account that I have 60 row and the user should be enable to select row i different row in different location in the table.

If I add a new background color if the row is selected, can it make it less userfriendly because there is too much color inside of table?

Any solution would be appreciated.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Use less color differentiation between the 2 existing ones, and use a 3rd, darker color for the selected/highlighted rows. You could improve UX further by allowing users to select a row by simply clicking on it, instead of allowing them to click on the checkbox only.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a big fan of alternating background colors between rows. White space and visual grouping should do the trick in most cases.

In your case, I would use a lower contrast between the background colors. Use just enough so that the eye notices the change.

As far as selection, I don't see anything wrong with using a different background color, a stronger one this time.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a concrete example of "stronger one this time"?

Comment: Yes, the intense blue in my example, or any other color that creates a contrast e.g. [accent colors](http://cmsresources.windowsphone.com/windowsphone/en-us/How-to/wp7/block/gettingstarted-concept-all-accent-colors.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about a simple border for selection?

Here is a simple example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L8ds3ja4/4/)

Answer (score -1):

If I'm interpreting you correctly, you can do this with jQuery. Once you've installed it, add a click event to each row that toggles a "selected" class:

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr', function(event){$(event.target).toggleClass('selected');})
```

If you have different "odd" and "even" classes for every other row, you CSS should look like this:

```
    .odd{
    ...
    }
    .odd.selected{
    ...
    }
    .even{
    ...
    }
    .even.selected{
    ...
    }
```

Keep in mind that toggling *can* be done *without jQuery*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880890/how-do-i-toggle-an-elements-class-in-pure-javascript and even *without JavaScript*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543956/toggle-class-on-html-element-without-jquery.

Comment: Hi @JohnHenry welcome to UX StackExchange!  I'm not sure that the OP is asking about how to *implement* banded tables (which would be out of scope for UX).  I believe the question is more UX oriented, as in:  does the use of banded design create too much color/distraction in the table?